# laravel migration "SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) "

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

am trying to do laravel migration but am getting this error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `urbancruise`.`#sql-18f8_112` (errno: 150 "Foreign key cons
  traint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`c
  ategory_id`) references `categories` (`id`))
```

here is my code

```
   Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name'); 
        $table->timestamps(); 
    });
}

public function down(){
    Schema::drop('categories');
}

public function up(){
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down(){
    Schema::drop('posts');
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I would suspect `categories.id` and `posts.category_id` don't have the same column type, length, or signed/unsigned value. Double check that they match.

Comment: how i dont understand

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating a foreign key, the `categories.id` and `posts.category_id` must have the same type.
Swap the `->bigInteger()` with `->integer()`should solve your problem:

Your categories migration:

```php
public function up(){
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name'); 
        $table->timestamps(); 
    });
}

public function down(){
    Schema::drop('categories');
}
```

In your posts migration:

```php
public function up(){
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id', false, true);
        //Or $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down(){
    Schema::drop('posts');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For clarity, I'd suggest changing `$table->integer('category_id', false, true);` to `$table->unsignedInteger('category_id')`

Comment: @ChrisForrence i've added it to the answer

Comment: @stachjj You'll have to roll back your migrations and re-run them for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key should always be of same type in both child and parent table.

In your case, `categories.id` is of type ٰINTEGER while `posts.category_id` is defined as BIGINT. Replacing your `posts` migration with below should work.

```php
public function up() {
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Did it help, @stach?